# Update-Timestamps Powershell command not working

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\folder_path\' -Recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
        (Get-Item $_.FullName).LastWriteTime=$(Get-Date -format o)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only updating the property *in-memory*.  To change the actual file on disk, you'll need to use `Set-ItemProperty`.  For example:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.FullName -Name LastWriteTime -Value (Get-Date)`